# What can I do to improve my questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I'll list below a few questions I've posted to SO that have received negative responses with some context:

- [Need to Convert Array Output to String Outside of a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60273807/need-to-convert-array-output-to-string-outside-of-a-for-loop)
- [Is there a way to store return values as an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841747/is-there-a-way-to-store-return-values-as-an-array-in-java)
- [How to append data files in a common (non-user specific) file location on Windows using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372864/how-to-append-data-files-in-a-common-non-user-specific-file-location-on-window)

I'll admit that some of these questions feel elementary to me now that I've got a bit more experience. However, my frustration stems from the fact that (to me at least) my questions seem well researched with a legitimate attempt at a solution, including edits for clarification and to make recommend improvements. Nonetheless, my account on SO has been question banned (likely in part due to submitting a number of "0 score" questions that are very specific to Eclipse Nebula packages).

Despite this, I'd really like to make an effort to ask more well received questions. I'd like to keep an general feedback open, but more specifically:

- Am I being too detailed in my questions and straying from stating a clear objective?
- Am I not clearly demonstrating research somehow?
- Could my formatting be better somehow?

It puzzles me a bit since very basic questions with non coding effort seem to be well-received for some reason.

Comment: In all 3 questions, the first thing I see is a large wall of text. Try breaking it down into paragraphs...

Comment: If your problem is an error message, lead with that.  Make the error message the title of your question.

Comment: I've edited this question to use bullets using CommonMark format (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). That is one thing you can learn to use to help people understand questions.

Comment: Avoid questions asking if something is a "best practice" or not.  Most of the time, there is no such thing. The right question to ask is "how do I accomplish [something] in a way that will satisfy [my specific goals]."

Comment: One of the downvote reasons is a lack of research effort, and you *say* you did a bunch of research. But there's nothing in the question indicating the research. Link to the articles you've found, the SO posts you've found helpful but didn't quite get you where you needed to go.

Comment: SO is not a help desk, but a collection of high quality (at least this is the goal) Q&As. The task of the asker is to provide a question, which is useful to others: the code should be minimal and polished and not just taken verbatim from your program, the description must be short and precise, without irrelevant Information.

Comment: Those posts are all missing complete [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since you don't give clear specification & explanation of how the minimal cut & paste & runnable code is trying to & failing to accomplish its task, plus you give a lot of unhelpful introductory text that isn't merely minimal necessary context. They aren't much more than wrong code with text that partly vaguely restates it & partly vaguely says what's wrong. (See my comment on the 1st linked question.) PS Always use a known seed to test calling a RNG.

Comment: Questions ban do not happen after only a couple bad questions.  Questions bans only happen after a pattern of low quality content.  A pattern that typically is more than 3 bad questions.  How many of your questions have been deleted?  You are only asking, for our feedback,with regards to questions that have not been deleted.  You have asked 17 questions, only 3 of those questions, have recieved downvotes.  While asking 15 questions that have a handful of upvotes is indeed problem, that wouldn't explain your question ban.  **So, how many of your questions, have been deleted?**

Comment: The three examples you provided a low quality questions.  In one of your examples, you are only looking for our opinion, questions seeking our opinion make horrible questions for a Q&A website.  I didn't bother to review the quality of your other 14 questions.

Comment: Deleted questions are: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56517475), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61092687), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61219673), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61240936), and [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61669231). The user is, indeed, under a question block.

Comment: @CodyGray Ahh, I see. Most of those were actually self-deleted without any understanding of how the algorithm worked. I undeleted (not a word I know) several of them. Another questions is opinion based, no gripes from me. I've noticed some quality improvements on more recent questions. Here's a thought though- why not sandbox users for their 1st 20 or so questions? Maybe make the 1st 20 questions free from downvotes and constructive feedback only. There's definitely a learning curve to asking proper questions, and I feel new users are often punished prematurely...

Comment: @ZachRieck downvotes *are constructive feedback*. Unless your goal is to start flame war please try to avoid comments like  "make the 1st 20 questions free from downvotes and constructive feedback only" - rehashing ideas that discussed dozens of times just because *you* decided to bring it up does not fare well on meta. Lack of ability to downvote comments does not mean it is ok to repost failed feature requests in comments.